# i am getting an error "$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl is not a function" while creating a popover using ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, popover

i have a popover , everything is fine according to the syntax , but i am getting this error "$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl is not a function" , how to fix this ?

my controller:

```
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/namespaceSettingPopover1.html', {
            scope: $scope,
          }).then(function(popover) {
            $scope.popover = popover;
        });

        $scope.openSettings = function($event) {
            $scope.popover.show($event);
        };

        $scope.closeSettings = function() {
            $scope.popover.hide();
        };

        // Execute action on hide popover
        $scope.$on('popover.hidden', function() {
        // Execute action
        });
```

html:

```
  <div class="ion-android-funnel" ng-click="openSettings($event)">
                            <img src="img/filter.png" class="filterImg" />
                        </div>
```

error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:19532 TypeError: $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (CreatorTrackerController.js:46)
    at invoke (ionic.bundle.js:12110)
    at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:12118)
    at ionic.bundle.js:16387
    at self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:47357)
    at Object.render (ionic.bundle.js:45614)
    at Object.init (ionic.bundle.js:45534)
    at self.render (ionic.bundle.js:47231)
    at self.register (ionic.bundle.js:47189)
    at updateView (ionic.bundle.js:52439)
```

Comment: Check if you've injected `$ionicPopover` correctly into the controller? If you're using the array notation for dependency injection, check the order of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to show your controller definition as well, like the name of controller and the dependency that you are using. Checking your error log, and assuming that your controller is **`CreatorTrackerController`**, the error occurs when you don't inject **`$ionicPopover`** service into your controller. Try the following.

```
 .controller('CreatorTrackerController', function($scope, $ionicPopover) {

    $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/namespaceSettingPopover1.html', {
                scope: $scope,
              }).then(function(popover) {
                $scope.popover = popover;
            });

            $scope.openSettings = function($event) {
                $scope.popover.show($event);
            };

            $scope.closeSettings = function() {
                $scope.popover.hide();
            };

            // Execute action on hide popover
            $scope.$on('popover.hidden', function() {
            // Execute action
            });

    });
```